# java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

```
     catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           progressDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog connection = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    NewsScreenActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("No Network Found")
                    .setMessage(
                            "Internet Connection Reqired To Use this Application,please try again latter")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {

                            //      progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).create();

            connection.show();


           Log.i("=================== UnknownHostException", "======");
       }
```

error:

```
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393): java.net.UnknownHostException: maritimeglobalnews.com
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-06 17:35:02.488: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-06 17:35:02.498: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
10-06 17:35:02.498: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-06 17:35:02.498: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-06 17:35:02.498: W/System.err(20393):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-06 17:35:02.498: W/System.err(20393):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity.getData(NewsScreenActivity.java:248)
10-06 17:35:02.498: W/System.err(20393):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity$AllDataAsyn.doInBackground(NewsScreenActivity.java:138)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity$AllDataAsyn.doInBackground(NewsScreenActivity.java:1)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-06 17:35:02.508: W/System.err(20393):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-06 17:35:02.538: W/dalvikvm(20393): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:786)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity.getData(NewsScreenActivity.java:450)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity$AllDataAsyn.doInBackground(NewsScreenActivity.java:138)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at com.MariTimeGlobalNews.NewsScreenActivity$AllDataAsyn.doInBackground(NewsScreenActivity.java:1)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-06 17:35:02.548: E/AndroidRuntime(20393):    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
  {
            // Your Alert Code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in onCreate methhod:

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```